# How to set which IP to use for a HTTP request?

Tags: go

I dont know if it's possible as the std lib does not state anything about the current address being used:

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

What I'm trying to do is set the source address for that http request, why? because I don't want to use my primary ip address for that kind of stuff...

Comment: Do you want something like proxy (or proxy itself)?

Comment: There are lots of services to obfuscate your IP address (e.g. proxies, VPN's, Tor). I suspect you'll need to do something like that rather than spoof your IP, otherwise you'd never get to see the page since it would be served to and IP address that's not yours.

Comment: I've several public ips on my server, What I want to do is select which one to use for web requests, for example like this: http://commandliners.com/2010/03/downloading-a-file-with-wget-through-a-specific-interface/ but I don't want to rely on extenal binaries... neither I want to spoof my ip address...

Comment: See the `LocalAddr` field of [`net.Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer). Most the standard packages have a way to specify your own dialer rather the default.

Comment: That could do it, I will check it out, I will try go-curl also.. I wonder why the downvote?

Comment: Also can someone bring up an answer with a working example ? thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set a custom Dialer in the Client's Transport.

```
// Create a transport like http.DefaultTransport, but with a specified localAddr
transport := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        LocalAddr: localAddr,
        DualStack: true,
    }).DialContext,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}

client := &http.Client{
    Transport: transport,
}
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, this is the resulting code as an experiment with a vpn on my development machine... http://play.golang.org/p/Bh8gfggLK-  also go-curl works with  easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_INTERFACE, "10.9.8.2").. thanks :)

Comment: @kainlite Are you sure that works? I'm getting an error from ResolveTCPAddr (you're ignoring it): dial tcp 10.9.8.2:8080->54.221.194.87:80: bind: can't assign requested address (I had to add a port on it because of a previous "couldn't find port" error).

Comment: You need to use an ip address from your net, I use that ip for a vpn

Comment: @JimB which IP address will the default Go http.Client choose?

Comment: @alex: the Go client doesn't choose an address, it works just like any other `connect` call and lets the system assign an address to the socket if there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a custom dialer with the specify IP works sometimes, but it is weird since sometimes it failed to work, while `curl` works normally.
After checking the source code of `curl`, I figured out why `curl` is able to specify what network interface to be used: `SO_BINDTODEVICE`. Unfortunately this is a Linux thing.

So compared to JimB's answer, my method has:

- Pro: Behaves as stable as `curl`, which is irrelevant from routing tables
- Con: Only support Linux. So you probably want to learn more about the build tags to write platform-specific code.

```golang
dialer := &net.Dialer{
    Control: func(network, address string, conn syscall.RawConn) error {
        var operr error
        if err := conn.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
            operr = unix.BindToDevice(int(fd), forceNetworkInterface)
        }); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return operr
    },
}

client = http.Client{
    Transport = &http.Transport{
        DialContext: dialer.DialContext,
    },
}
```

In addition, `curl` performs `SO_BINDTODEVICE` which behaves like the above code. And for non-Linux platforms, or when `SO_BINDTODEVICE` fails, `curl` sets the local IP address just as JimB's answer does. So you can first try my code and then use JimB's answer as a fallback.

See [the source code of curl](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/3879d812adae3cf9d70237df9d3fd6b7d8d7bded/lib/connect.c) for details.