# make http request with a specified ethernet ip

Tags: go

I have several public ip addresses on my machine. I want to specify which one to use for a request.

I can do it using curl:

```
curl --interface 111.222.333.444 https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address | grep "Your IP address"
```

where `111.222.333.444` is one of my local ip addresses which I am using to make requests to the internet.

How to do the same using `golang`?

## [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552447/how-to-set-which-ip-to-use-for-a-http-request) method...

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var localAddr = "111.222.333.444"
    localAddress, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", localAddr)

    // Create a transport like http.DefaultTransport, but with a specified localAddr
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            LocalAddr: localAddress,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }

    response, err := client.Get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        var contentsStr = string(contents)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", contentsStr)
        var doc = DocByHtmlString(contentsStr)

        doc.Find("div").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
            attr, exists := s.Attr("class")
            if exists {
                if attr == "ip" {
                    fmt.Println(s.Text())
                    fmt.Println("expected ip is " + localAddr)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func DocByHtmlString(html string) *goquery.Document {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(bytes.NewBufferString(html))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return doc
}
```

... gives me always the following result:

```
Your IP Address Is: 555.666.777.888 // main IP address on my machine
expected ip is 111.222.333.444
```

## [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410764/dial-with-a-specific-address-interface-golang) method

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ief, err := net.InterfaceByName("eth0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    addrs, err := ief.Addrs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tcpAddr := &net.TCPAddr{
        IP: addrs[3].(*net.IPNet).IP,
        // Port: 8080,
    }
    d := net.Dialer{LocalAddr: tcpAddr}
    conn, err2 := d.Dial("tcp", "www.whatismyip.com:80")
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(`conn.LocalAddr()`)
    fmt.Println(conn.LocalAddr())
    fmt.Println(`conn.RemoteAddr()`)
    fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr())
    defer conn.Close()
    bytesResult, err3 := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
    if err3 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err3)
    }
    fmt.Println(`string(bytesResult)`)
    fmt.Println(string(bytesResult))
}
```

gives output

```
conn.LocalAddr()
111.222.333.213:37036 
conn.RemoteAddr()
141.101.120.15:80
                     // 15 seconds pause
string(bytesResult)
                     // empty string
```

## ifcongif

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-63-generic x86_64)

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.208  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: de90::216:3cff:fe56:698c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:942000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:336708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:133860794 (133.8 MB)  TX bytes:84577381 (84.5 MB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.209  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.212  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.213  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.216  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.217  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.220  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:6    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.221  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:7    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.224  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:3c:96:69:8c  
          inet addr:111.222.333.225  Bcast:111.222.333.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Specify a port in `net.TCPAddr` (second method). It seems like it's defaulting to 80 and that port requires privileges and may already be bound.

Comment: @thwd  with port it doesn't give an error but gives empty response in 10 seconds (added code above)

Comment: Smells like a timeout of some sort.

Comment: Your 3rd example isn't going to print anything, because you're not sending an HTTP request.

Comment: @JimB how to send HTTP request using `net.Dialer{LocalAddr: tcpAddr}`?

Comment: The answers you linked to are both mine, and the first is this exact same question. If that doesn't work, we need more information about your network configuration, OS, etc.

Comment: @JimB it's ubuntu, I added `ifcongif` information above.

Comment: The second example you have makes no sense, because you don't have an interface named `en0`, and the last one doesn't make a request. How about you send a request using the last example? You could also make a Dial function that logs what it's doing as well as the LocalAddr and RemoteAddr of the actual connection once it's made.

Comment: @JimB it was a typo with `en0` - my local computer trials. I updated the second trial above with printing  `LocalAddr` and `RemoteAddr`. Looks like the correct the ip is choosed. Why do you say I don't make a request? This is request `conn, err2 := d.Dial("tcp", "www.whatismyip.com:80")`, isn't?

Comment: No, that's not an HTTP request, that's creating a TCP connection.  You're example shows it's using the address you want. You're going to have to log what the transport dialer is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @JimB. Working solution:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ief, err := net.InterfaceByName("eth0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    addrs, err := ief.Addrs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tcpAddr := &net.TCPAddr{
        IP: addrs[3].(*net.IPNet).IP, // Choosing ip address number 3
    }
    d := net.Dialer{LocalAddr: tcpAddr}
    conn, err2 := d.Dial("tcp", "www.whatismyip.com:80")
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(`conn.LocalAddr()`)
    fmt.Println(conn.LocalAddr())
    fmt.Println(`conn.RemoteAddr()`)
    fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr())
    defer conn.Close()

    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy:               http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        Dial:                (&net.Dialer{LocalAddr: tcpAddr}).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }

    response, err := client.Get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        var contentsStr = string(contents)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", contentsStr)
        var doc = DocByHtmlString(contentsStr)

        doc.Find("div").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
            attr, exists := s.Attr("class")
            if exists {
                if attr == "ip" {
                    fmt.Println(s.Text())
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func DocByHtmlString(html string) *goquery.Document {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(bytes.NewBufferString(html))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return doc
}
```

Prints in the end `Your IP Address Is: 111.222.333.213` as expected.